# Using || operator

Tags: c, xml

Am using a XML sort of language which doesnt have '||' operator. How can i achieve the effect of this operator? The language doesnt support ternary operator also. Other than if-else approach is there any other way to achieve this?

The expression is, if((x == 2) || (y == 2)), and should achieve this without ||, ?: , if-else.. thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify "XML sort of language". Do you mean XPath?

Comment: If you have `&&` and `!` you can replace `a || b` by `!(!a && !b)`

Comment: Admittedly you're getting good shots-in-the-dark as answers, but you really should edit the question to identify the language.  Control flow doesn't even make sense in an XML-sort of language!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
if (x == 2) {
    flag = true;
}
if (y == 2) {
    flag = true;
}
if (flag) {
    // do something
}
```

---

Or this:

```
if ((x == 2) | (y == 2)) {
    // do something
}
```

Note that this uses the non-short-circuit OR operator `|` rather than `||`.

Answer (score 3):

```
temp = false;
if (x==2)
{
   doSomething();
   temp = true;
}
if (y==2)
{
   if (!temp)
       doSomething();
}
```

This also could work

```
if (x==2)
{
   doSomething();
}
else
{
   if (y==2)
       doSomething();
}
```

Comment: If x==2 and y==2 then DoSomething twice?

Comment: Except if x==2 and y==2 doSomething() will be called twice

Comment: But the condition is separate.

Comment: I see your answer is now the same as mine :-)

Comment: @ Stephen: I'm sorry my edit made his answer the same as yours. If I'd seen yours I'd just upvoted yours.

Answer (score 1):

Split the or explicitly:

```
if (x == 2) {
  ... do stuff 
} else if (y == 2) { 
  ... do the same stuff 
} else { 
  condition not fulfilled 
}
```

Now, without else ... I know one 'xml sort of language' with that: XSL(T), in which you have a `<xsl:if>` but not the obvious `<xsl:else>`. What you do have there however is a more general `<xsl:choose>` that supports multiple conditions using `<xsl:when>` and also an `<xsl:otherwise>` to express the 'other' cases.

So, try searching in your 'xml sort of language' whether it maybe supports a case/switch/choose functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!((x != 2) && (y != 2))) {
    work();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if((x == 2) + (y == 2))
{
  do_something();
}
```

It will behave slightly different than the OR-operator because the + operator can't do short-circuit evaluation.

The control-flow of the program will be the same though..

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is repeating the set of instructions executed or specified for the case of x==2 and y==2. The problem here seems to come from the language, as it should at least support basic logical operators in order to be usable.

Answer (score 0):

Does this "XML sort of language" support `&&`?  If so, invert the logic:

`if ((x == 2) || (y == 2))` converts to: `if (!((x != 2) && (y != 2)))`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
boolean doIt = (x == 2);

if (!doit) {
    doIt = (y == 2);
}

if (doIt) {

   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

if ((x == 2) && (x+y == 4))
{

}
else
{

}